# Derivative of $(X^2-1)^m$ , Legendre polynomial

Tags: polynomials, legendre-polynomials

Let :

- $n \in \mathbb{N}$
- $\Phi(P)=[ (X^2-1)P']'$ for $P \in \mathbb{R}_n[X]$
- $m \leq n$
- $W_m(X)=(X^2-1)^m$
- $P_m(X)= k_m \frac{ d^m}{dX^m}[ W_m(X)]$ with $k_m$ such that $P_m(1)=1$

We want to express $\Phi(P_m)$ as a function of $P_m$, in fact that $P_m$ is an eigenvector of $\Phi$.

---

My attempt :

Let $f(X)= (X-1)^m$ and $g(X)=(X+1)^m$. $\forall 0 \leq k \leq m-1, ~ f^{(k)}(1) =0$

$\frac{ d ^ m }{ d X^m} (X^2-1) =\frac{ d ^ m }{ d X^m} (fg) = \sum_{k=0}^{m}  \binom{m}{k} f^{(k)} g^{ ( m-k) }$ so

$\frac{ d ^ m }{ d X^m} (X^2-1)|_{X=1} =  \binom{m}{m}  f^{(m)}|_{X=1} g^{ ( 0) }|_{X=1} =  1 \times m ! \times 2^m $

but $P_m(1)= 1$ so $k_m= \frac{1}{2^m m!}$

We notice that $ (X^2-1) W_m'(X)= 2m XW_m(X)$

I derive $1$ time $\Phi(W_m)= (2m W_m + 2m X W_m')$, then $m$ times.

$
\begin{align*}
 \frac{ d^m  }{ d X^m} \Phi(W_m) &= 2m \frac{ d^m}{ d X^m} W_m  + 2m  \frac{ d^m  }{ d X^m} (X W_m) \\
&= \frac{2m}{k_m} P_m(X) + 2 m \sum_{k=0}^{m}      \frac{ d^k  }{ d X^k}     W_m       \frac{ d^{(m-k)}  }{ d X^{(m-k)} }   X     \\
&= \frac{2m}{k_m} P_m(X) + 2 m \sum_{k=m-1}^{m}   \binom{m}{k}    \frac{ d^k  }{ d X^k}     W_m       \frac{ d^{(m-k)}  }{ d X^{(m-k)} }   X     \\
&= \frac{2m}{k_m} P_m(X) + 2 m ( W_m^{(m)} X + m W_m^{(m-1)} ) \\
&=\frac{2m}{k_m} P_m(X) + 2 m (  \frac{1}{k_m} P_m(X) X + m W_m^{(m-1)} ) \\
\end{align*}
$